# What if Paul Atreides failed the Gom Jabbar?

Tags: dune

I've wondered about the possibility that Mohiam's test was only the threat of death, that she would not have actually killed Paul for failing. However, Jessica's reaction to his success "My son lives!" heavily implies that the test was in fact lethal.

What would Jessica and Mohiam have done with the body of a dead ducal heir on their hands? Maybe '*Weekend at Leto's*'? lol

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  It's an interesting question, but I don't know if we can give you a good answer.  It seems possible there won't be much in-universe information to draw on, which would make answers speculative.  This might be more clear if you read [ask] and the "what not to ask" page of the [help/dont-ask].

Comment: the indications given in the text give every reason to believe that when Mohiam said he'd die, she meant it (imo)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's very obvious he would be dead. I don't see any reason for the Bene Gesserit to spare his life if he failed he was after all expendable they wanted a daughter he was never part of their plan.

Comment: Was "Bene Jesuit" deliberate or a Freudian slip?

Comment: Neither it was a typo I'm writing this on my phone.

Comment: Well, either way, it gave me a chuckle. :)

Comment: Technically, the question asks what they'd do with the body.  But since the gom jabbar is a test of humanity, if he failed, Paul would not be considered human, therefore it would not be cannibalism!